# Swift – setup more than one fillColor in MKCircle

Tags: swift, mapkit, fill, radius, mkcircle

I'm trying to have my `MKCircle` `fillColor` change when the markerType is different. For example, if the `markerType` is "airport", then the fill should be red, and if it is "Sea Plane Base" then the fill should be black.

```
// MARK: Radius overlay
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKCircle {
        let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)

        for markerType in airports {
            if markerType.markerType == "airport" {
                circle.strokeColor = UIColor.red
                circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
                circle.lineWidth = 1
            } else {
                circle.strokeColor = UIColor.black
                circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
                circle.lineWidth = 1
            }
        }

        return circle
    } else {
        return MKPolylineRenderer()
    }
}
```

I'm using this function to show the radius.

```
func mainAirportRadius(radius: CLLocationDistance) {
    //MARK: Airport location
    for coordinate in airports {
        let center = coordinate.coordinate
        let circle = MKCircle(center: center, radius: radius)
        mapView.add(circle)
    }
}
```

Then I call it in the `viewDidLoad` method

```
mainAirportRadius(radius: 8046.72)
```

Comment: What is the current behavior? I.e. how is it acting vs. how you expect it to act?

Comment: It is only returning the 
'red" color for the fill

Comment: Take a look at my answer below. I would suggest putting a `print` statement under `for markerType in airports {`...I expect that you will see `circle` attributes are being changed not once, but `length(airports)` number of times.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I get this error.    Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list of type '(MKCircle, String)'